# Nginx config order of operations

Tags: nginx

Apologies if this is answered or documented already but I was confused on this so I'm hoping the community can provide some insight.

The below example is specifically for `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set_header` config directives, but my overall question is more of a "H*ow does Nginx config handle ordering in general?*" type of question.

I came across some working nginx config, with a location block such as this:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://internal.example.com/req;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $auth_resp_x_user;
  }
```

This confused me since I've always been under the impression that ordering matters, and the headers would need to be set BEFORE the `proxy_pass` line. Such as this:

```
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $auth_resp_x_user;

    proxy_pass http://internal.example.com/req;
  }
```

Questions:

- Does the ordering actually matter?
- If it doesn't matter here, is that specific to proxy_pass? It does matter in other nginx config lines, correct?
- Is this type of ordering/precedence documented anywhere? (Sorry if it is, I'm not seeing it)

Thank you for any insight and help.

Answer (score 2):

In general, nginx configuration is declarative. This means, every configuration directive has an effect of certain separately defined processing step in handling a request.

This means that in general the order of directives inside a specific scope does not matter.

However, there are exceptions to the general rule:

- `location` blocks that match regular expressions are dependent on order. The first matching block is used to process the request.
- `rewrite` module processes directives imperatively

The only reference for this fact I could find is in [IfIsEvil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article.